# Typesetting A when a register is 1, B when 2, etc

Tags: tikz-pgf, registers

I have a register `\count0=<some-value>` and need to get the letter of the alphabet on the index of `\count0`. That is, if it is 1, I need an A, if 2, a B, etc.

Is this possible?

I'm reluctant sharing an MWE as it seems to overcomplicate things a bit:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=7, minimum size=5cm] (A) {};
\foreach \i in {1,...,7}{
    \count0=8
    \advance\count0 by -\i
    \node[circle, label=above:\scriptsize\the\count0, fill=black, minimum size=4pt, inner sep=0pt] (\the\count0) at (A.corner \i) {};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

With the tikz package and the shapes.geometric tikz library.

This draws seven nodes labelled 1 .. 7 on a circle. I need to have A .. G instead of 1 .. 7.

Comment: `\symbol{\numexpr64+\count0\relax}` will do. But use `\count255` throughout, not `\count0`.

Comment: @egreg thanks very much, also for the second note, I forgot about that for a moment. Could you turn this into an answer? Or is this a duplicate? I couldn't find anything, but it must've been asked before.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need a counter here, `\foreach` can loop over letters.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=7, minimum size=5cm] (A) {};
    \foreach[count=\i] \a in {G,...,A}{
        \node[
          circle,
          label=above:\a,
          fill=black,
          minimum size=4pt,
          inner sep=0pt
        ] (N\i) at (A.corner \i) {};}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**UPDATE:** Changed to make it clockwise.

Answer (score 11):

## The power of `\foreach`

The loop macro `\foreach` of TikZ/pgf has powerful features, which can be used here to get and calculate the three variables for the uppercase letters and their number representation, and the numbers in the opposite direction for the node positions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=7, minimum size=5cm] (A) {};
\foreach \A [count=\i, evaluate=\i as \j using int(8-\i)] in {G, ..., A}{
    \node[
      circle,
      label=above:\scriptsize\A,
      fill=black,
      minimum size=4pt,
      inner sep=0pt,
    ] (\j) at (A.corner \i) {};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

## `\@Alph` for the uppercase letter

LaTeX uses `\Alph` for its counters to generate uppercase letters. The command, which works on numbers instead of counters is `\@Alph`. Because of `@`, either `\makeatletter` ... `\makeatother` is needed or the following `\csname` ... `\endcsname` construct:

```
\csname @Alph\endcsname{\the\count0}
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=7, minimum size=5cm] (A) {};
\foreach \i in {1,...,7}{
    \count0=8
    \advance\count0 by -\i
    \node[
      circle,
      label=above:\scriptsize\csname @Alph\endcsname{\the\count0},
      fill=black,
      minimum size=4pt,
      inner sep=0pt,
    ] (\the\count0) at (A.corner \i) {};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## LaTeX counter with `\Alph`

The following example uses a LaTeX counter `AlphNode` and `\pgfmathsetcounter` for the calculation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\newcounter{AlphNode}
\renewcommand*{\theAlphNode}{\Alph{AlphNode}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=7, minimum size=5cm] (A) {};
\foreach \i in {1,...,7}{
    \pgfmathsetcounter{AlphNode}{8-\i}
    \node[
      circle,
      label=above:\scriptsize\theAlphNode,
      fill=black,
      minimum size=4pt,
      inner sep=0pt,
    ] (\the\count0) at (A.corner \i) {};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

You could use `\Alph` or its internal sibling `\@Alph`, but since you probably want ASCII characters and not language localized characters, `\symbol` is better.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\newcount\stapscount

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=7, minimum size=5cm] (A) {};
\foreach \i in {1,...,7}{
    \stapscount=8
    \advance\stapscount by -\i
    \node[
      circle,
      label=above:\scriptsize\symbol{\numexpr64+\stapscount\relax},
      fill=black,
      minimum size=4pt,
      inner sep=0pt
    ] (\the\stapscount) at (A.corner \i) {};
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This uses the fact that the ASCII code for A is 65.

Avoid using `\count0` when typesetting. It's true that `\foreach` does its job in a group and that `\end{tikzpicture}` is responsible for printing, but in this case it's better to use a specific counter.